# IntelliJ: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0 ¿Cómo puedo quitar ese warning?

Tags: java, java-8, intellij-idea, ide, jvm

Al Arrancar una APP o TEST en el IDE de **IntelliJ** en la consola, sección run me aparece este **error**:

```
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
```

Me gustaría eliminarlo, pero adjunto en la primer respuesta, la posible solución pero no me siento seguro de eliminar archivos dados por IntelliJ

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

C://RutaCarpetaJetBrains/IntelliJ/bin/(archivos a eliminar)

archivos a eliminar:

```
idea.exe.vmoptions
idea64.exe.vmoptions
```

Comment: En el soporte de jetbrains hay referencias a ese warning, y una posible solución: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000421640-How-to-remove-MaxPermSize-from-run-configuration-VM-options-

Comment: @Benito-B Muchas gracias Benito, pero la solución que recomiendas es editar el pom.xml del proyecto, en este caso al ser un proyecto financiero, no lo veo viable, luego adjunta una imagen con unos checks que se encuentran iguales a mi IDE.